# СarouselView does not display content

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

СarouselView does not display content. I have the following code in the **AppShell.axml** 
for the whole day I can’t figure out how to make this work. Help make a working code.

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" 
       xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
       xmlns:d="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms/design"
       xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
       mc:Ignorable="d"
       xmlns:local="clr-namespace:test.Views"
       BackgroundColor="Azure"
       x:Class="test.AppShell">

    <CarouselView HorizontalOptions="Center" NumberOfSideItems="1">
            <CarouselView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackLayout>
                       <Frame HasShadow="True"
                       BorderColor="DarkGray"
                       CornerRadius="5"
                       Margin="20"
                       HeightRequest="300"
                       HorizontalOptions="Center"
                       VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand">
                            <StackLayout>
                               <Label Text="11111111111"
                               FontAttributes="Bold"
                               FontSize="Large"
                               HorizontalOptions="Center"
                               VerticalOptions="Center" />

                            </StackLayout>
                        </Frame>
                    </StackLayout>
                </DataTemplate>
            </CarouselView.ItemTemplate>

    </CarouselView>
</ContentPage>
```

I have the following code in the AppShell.axml.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Xamarin.Forms;
namespace test
{
    public partial class AppShell : ContentPage
    {

        public AppShell()
        {
            InitializeComponent();




        }

    }
}
```

I tried such an example and it works, but I need the option to work from above.

```
<CarouselView>
    <CarouselView.ItemsSource>
        <x:Array Type="{x:Type x:String}">
            <x:String>Baboon</x:String>
            <x:String>Capuchin Monkey</x:String>
            <x:String>Blue Monkey</x:String>
            <x:String>Squirrel Monkey</x:String>
            <x:String>Golden Lion Tamarin</x:String>
            <x:String>Howler Monkey</x:String>
            <x:String>Japanese Macaque</x:String>
        </x:Array>
    </CarouselView.ItemsSource>
</CarouselView>
```

Answer (score 1):

Firstly why you place a `carsouselView` in the Appshell.xaml? I think the AppShell.Xaml is only to set the App configurations.

you can write code in the AppShell.xaml to layout the App menu or flylayout.

if you do not specify a `ItemsSource` to `CarouselView` It will not renderer.

you can make the ItemsSource by BindingContext.

Comment: please give an example how to make the ItemsSource by BindingContext. In general, I need to display several pages in the carousel. Example, but it also displays a white screen, although scroll gestures are visible. ```<CarouselView> <CarouselView.ItemTemplate> <DataTemplate> <StackLayout> <local:View2></local:View2><local:View1></local:View1> </StackLayout> </DataTemplate> </CarouselView.ItemTemplate> </CarouselView>```

Answer (score 1):

Do you want to achieve the result like following GIF?

[image]

If so, you could show the content in the `CarouselView` by DataBinding.

Step 1: Create a Model for your `CarouselView`, I create it like following code.

```
public class MyModel
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Step 2: create a viewModel for your `CarouselView`(we can add the content that we want them to display).

```
  public  class MyModelView: BaseViewModel
{
    public ObservableCollection<MyModel> MyModels { get; set; }
    public MyModelView()
    {
        MyModels = new ObservableCollection<MyModel>();
        MyModels.Add(new MyModel() { Name="test1"});
        MyModels.Add(new MyModel() { Name = "test2" });
        MyModels.Add(new MyModel() { Name = "test3" });
        MyModels.Add(new MyModel() { Name = "test4" });
        MyModels.Add(new MyModel() { Name = "test5" });
        MyModels.Add(new MyModel() { Name = "test6" });


    }

}
```

Step 3: please add the `ItemsSource` for your `CarouselView` and binding the properties for xamarin forms control(`Label`)

```
 <CarouselView HorizontalOptions="Center" NumberOfSideItems="1" ItemsSource="{ Binding MyModels}">
    <CarouselView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackLayout>
                <Frame HasShadow="True"
                   BorderColor="DarkGray"
                   CornerRadius="5"
                   Margin="20"
                   HeightRequest="300"
                   HorizontalOptions="Center"
                   VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand">
                    <StackLayout>
                        <Label Text="{Binding Name}"
                           FontAttributes="Bold"
                           FontSize="Large"
                           HorizontalOptions="Center"
                           VerticalOptions="Center" />

                    </StackLayout>
                </Frame>
            </StackLayout>
        </DataTemplate>
    </CarouselView.ItemTemplate>

</CarouselView>
```

Step 4： backend code for your `CarouselView`.To bind your ModelView for layout.

```
   BindingContext = new MyModelView();
```

Here is an example project. you can refer to it.

https://github.com/851265601/MyShellCarouselView

Comment: @alexandr f Are there any update for this issue, if the reply is helpful, please mark it as answer, it will help others who  have similar issue.